If $F$ is an endofunctor on the category of abelian groups $G \mapsto G_{tors}$, then $R^1F(A) \cong A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$
I am trying to find all right derived functors of the functor $F: Ab \to Ab$ defined as an endofunctor on the category of abelian groups $G \mapsto G_{tors}$.
I have proven that $R^iF = 0$ for all $i > 1$, and since $F$ can be proven to be a left exact functor, we have that $R^0F \cong F$. It remains to find what $R^1F$ is, or more precisely prove that $R^1F(A) \cong A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. I am not sure how to proceed. Part of that is finding an injective abelian group $G$ for a given abelian group $A$ such that there is an injection from $A$ to $G$ and analyze what happends to the exact sequence $0 \to A \to G \xrightarrow{\pi} G/A$ when we apply $F$ to it. I know the definition of an injective object, but since it seems quite abstract to me (including the proof of the fact that every $\mathbb{Z}$-module injects into an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module), I would appreciate your help in proving $R^1F(A) \cong A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Hint: can you show that your proposed $R^1F$ is right exact and find its first left derived functor?

Actually, now I am not quite sure that the above hint immediately leads to a solution.

This might be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555666/derived-functor-of-derived-functor

$\newcommand{\tors}{_{\mathrm{tors}}}\newcommand{\tor}{\operatorname{Tor}}\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}\require{AMScd}$I just answered this question, as well as its friend (find the left and right derived functors of $G\mapsto G/G\tors$) for someone else, yesterday - maybe you share a class? :) Anyway, this isn't too easy by hand but the snake lemma becomes very useful. I am basically writing up a minor refinement of the ideas of this "someone else". Motto: write down as many exact sequences as you can, then maybe something will reveal itself.
This post is mildly verbose to give motivations and explanations for what's going on and why it's going on.
$\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$... where does that come from? We surely want to think about the exact sequence $0\to\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\to0$. I know that since $\Bbb Q$ is flat, if I take a group $A$ we have an exact sequence: $0\to\tor(A,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)\to A\to A\otimes\Bbb Q\to A\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\to0$. It seems pretty reasonable to want to calculate this kernel, the tor group; considering the exact sequence $0\to A\tors\to A\to A/A\tors\to0$, with the last term being torsionfree hence flat, we realise $\tor(A,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)\cong\tor(A\tors,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)$ which is the kernel of $A\tors\to A\tors\otimes\Bbb Q=0$ and we get natural identifications $\tor(A,\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)\cong A\tors$. So, maybe you already knew it but we get to compute the kernel and say $0\to A\tors\to A\to A\otimes\Bbb Q\to A\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\to0$ is exact. Exercise: think about naturality and how I get to know $A\tors\to A$ here is in fact the canonical inclusion of subgroups.
What do we know about injective Abelian groups? They are divisible. So if I'm thinking about whether or not I can say anything more when the $A$ above is injective, I can realise divisiblity implies $A\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z=0$.
So fix $G$; injectively resolve - and you know I only need two steps, for Abelian groups, since $\Bbb Z$ is a hereditary ring (more elementary arguments are available too) - $0\to G\to \J\to \I\to0$, $\J,\I$ injective. I know that $(-)\tors$ is appearing as a kernel of the sequences above, and that $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ appears as the cokernels, so this suggests I should write down something amenable to the snake lemma.
On that note, consider that the following is exact: $$\begin{CD}0@>>>G@>>>\J@>>>\I@>>>0\\@VVV@VVV@VVV@VVV@VVV\\0@>>>G\otimes\Bbb Q@>>>\J\otimes\Bbb Q@>>>\I\otimes\Bbb Q@>>>0\end{CD}$$We don't need the top left or bottom right zeroes, but they're there anyway. I am crucially using flatness of $\Bbb Q$ once again, to justify (left) exactness of the bottom row. The Snake Lemma applies now; let's first extend this to a three-by-three, using the previous kernel/cokernel calculations: $$\begin{CD}G\tors@>>>\J\tors@>>>\I\tors\\@VVV@VVV@VVV\\G@>>>\J@>>>\I\\@VVV@VVV@VVV\\G\otimes\Bbb Q@>>>\J\otimes\Bbb Q@>>>\I\otimes\Bbb Q\\@VVV@VVV@VVV\\G\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z@>>>0\cong\J\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z@>>>0\cong\I\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\end{CD}$$
So the snake lemma tells me that there is a connecting homomorphism such that: $$0\to G\tors\to \J\tors\to \I\tors\to G\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\to0$$Is exact. This diagram is natural in $G$ and the resolution, and the snake lemma also has a naturality property, so thankfully we conclude a natural isomorphism: $$R^1(-)\tors\cong(-)\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$$From this sequence. We also see the connecting homomorphism for this delta functor can be obtained in the above way, where $\J,\I$ instead may be any groups. Remember derived functors also include the data of (co)boundary homomorphisms!

You could also have made an effaceability argument. Use the above calculations and snake lemma to setup to realise $(-)\tors,(-)\otimes\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z,0,0,0,\cdots$ fit together as a $\delta$-functor of cohomological type; then realise this erases injective (divisible) groups in positive degree, and use the Grothendieck effaceability principle to conclude this is a universal $\delta$-functor - starting with $(-)\tors$ - thus uniquely isomorphic with any other model of $R^\ast(-)\tors$
